# Are there any databases for gene co-expression or expression pattern clustering?

Tags: database, public-databases, differential-expression, gene-expression, coexpression

I am currently working on gene clustering based on co-expression pattern in mouse brain. The problem is I do not have some solid way to test my result. Are there any suggestions for databases indicating groups of genes that co-express (in mouse brain), or even better indicating some similarity metrics between each pair of genes based on expression pattern?

Also, I do want some databases for differentially-expressed genes ;)

PS: By "differentially-expressed" I am referring to a pair of genes whose expression patterns in a single individual differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- http://www.informatics.jax.org/expression.shtml
- http://www.emouseatlas.org/emage/home.php

Other potential databases of interest:

- https://biokeanos.com/search?q=co-expression+%2Bmouse

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!  The first two seems to be developmental expressions, while the third database is very helpful!  This site looks quite good: https://gemma.msl.ubc.ca/